# Why is the selectedindexchanged event firing only once in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have two drop down lists,the first one is ddlSubjectArea and below is it's source code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjectArea" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="20px"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubjectArea_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="160px" 
                meta:resourcekey="ddlSubjectAreaResource1" class="notranslate">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the code for the second one:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompetency1" runat="server" Width="150px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>                                        
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSubjectArea" runat="server" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is the code for the selectedindexchanged event of the first dropdownlist.

```
protected void ddlSubjectArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblSubjectMasterDLL.BindSubjectOnSubjectArea(ddlSubjectName, Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubjectArea.SelectedItem.Value));
    bIsMultipleCompetency = tblSubjectAreaMasterDLL.IsMultipleCompetency(Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubjectArea.SelectedValue));
    MultipleCompetencySetting();
}
```

The visibility of the second dropdownlist depends on the first dropdownlist's selected index.The selectedindexchanged event fires once but after that it does not fire.I have tried selecting different values every time but had no success.Where am I going wrong?

Another piece of information that I would like to provide is that even the page load event is getting called only once.Also if I remove the update panels,everything works normally.

I would like to add one more piece of information:If I set EnableEventValidation=false for the page,things start working as expected.I have also heard that setting EnableEventValidation to false is not recommended.

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?", You are using update panels. Basically they are very buggy in my experience and I have seen this exact bug a few years ago. Try using JQuery and some kind of web service.

Comment: I know this isn't solving the issue, but have you tried "UpdatePanel3.Update()" from the OnClick event?